# pgfplots: How to draw mesh of 3D plot only in y direction (but not in x direction)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

Assumed we draw a simple 3D plot with `pgfplots`.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
    x;y;z
    0;0;4
    0;1;4
    0;2;4
    1;0;3
    1;1;3
    1;2;3
    2;0;2
    2;1;2
    2;2;2
    3;0;1
    3;1;1
    3;2;1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[table/col sep = semicolon]
            \addplot3[mesh, scatter, mesh/cols=3] table[x=x, y=y, z=z] {testdata.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Question:**

- Would it be possible to draw the `mesh` only in `y` direction, but not in `x` direction? You can see the desired result in the next screenshot
- The `mesh` colors depending on the `z`-value can be preserved

---

**Screenshot of the desired state:**

[image: Screenshot of the desired state]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just loop over ordinary plots.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
    x;y;z
    0;0;4
    0;1;4
    0;2;4
    1;0;3
    1;1;3
    1;2;3
    2;0;2
    2;1;2
    2;2;2
    3;0;1
    3;1;1
    3;2;1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[table/col sep = semicolon]
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,3}
            {\addplot3[scatter,%mesh, scatter, mesh/cols=3,
             %x filter/.expression={x == #1 ? x : nan}
             restrict x to domain=#1:#1] table[x=x, y=y, z=z] {testdata.csv};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep the colors of the lines, you could do

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
    x;y;z
    0;0;4
    0;1;4
    0;2;4
    1;0;3
    1;1;3
    1;2;3
    2;0;2
    2;1;2
    2;2;2
    3;0;1
    3;1;1
    3;2;1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[table/col sep = semicolon]
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,3}
            {\addplot3[scatter,mesh, scatter, mesh/cols=1,
             %x filter/.expression={x == #1 ? x : nan}
             restrict x to domain=#1:#1
             ] table[x=x, y=y, z=z] {testdata.csv};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! What does `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` do exactly? I understand it repeats drawing the plot, but why is necessary to limit it to a specific range/domain like `{0,...,3}`?

Comment: @Dave It is like a `\foreach` loop except that it avoids some expansion problems.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, I never used that before - seems to be a bit complicated. :-) I just repeat drawing the plot with this, no? Thank you!